# Reachability not work

Tags: ios, iphone, reachability

I use this method to check connection:

```
- (BOOL)networkConnection {
    return [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://medsolutions.ru"] currentReachabilityStatus];
}
```

Its all work in simulator, and on iPhone 6, but not work with iPhone 4S. I mean, block:

```
if (!([self networkConnection] == NotReachable)){
```

Always return false, which means that there is no connection, but actually it is connected via wi-fi.

Comment: `BOOL` ≠ `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am checking rechability in one of my projects something like,

```
 if ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable)
    {
        NSLog(@"not available");
    }
 else{   
         NSLog(@"available");
    }
```

if you want to check particular host then,

```
  if ([[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://medsolutions.ru"]currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) {

     NSLog(@"not available");
}
else{   
     NSLog(@"available");
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 3):

That method returns a `NetworkStatus` `enum`, not a `BOOL`:

```
- (NetworkStatus)networkConnection {
    return [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://medsolutions.ru"] currentReachabilityStatus];
}
```

You must be ignoring several compiler warnings to get this far.  Not a good idea.

Comment: I have fixed it in my answer.  Change the return type of the method.

Comment: thanks. But i have to admit that i did not have any compiler warning,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this third party highly rated https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability
 It work perfectly in my project